# What's the best way to share the model between two play framework application?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean

I have two (possibly more) applications written in Play 2.4.x.
I want to start delegating different functionality to different applications and host them in different servers. Now, my problem is that most of this components will all need to share the same model.
I am using Ebean and MySQL.

Is there an easy way to do that? I googled how to create modules in Play but most of the results refer to Play 1.x or are not very well documented.

Is there a way to packetise the model in an external dependency or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is!  The following will show you how to create a sub-project, package it, publish to your local .ivy repository, and import it into a parent project.

#### First create the sub-project

- Create a new java minimal java seed:

> $activator new

- Add some common code to this new project under a specific package name like:

> project-root/src/java/main/com/mycompany/commons

- Edit the build.sbt

  ```
  name := """mycompany-commons"""
  organization := "com.mycompany.commons"
  version := "1.0"
  scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq()
  ```
- Create the package (jar), in the console, from the project root, run:

> $activator package

At this point you should have a jar that can be added to a locally hosted package repository.  For this example I'll show you had to add it to your local .ivy repository

---

#### Publish and Use sub-project

While still in the sub-project directory:

> $activator publish-local

Now that you have your lib published to your local ivy repository, add the new dependency to your **parent project**.

- In build.sbt add the following to libraryDependencies:

  `"com.mycompany.commons" % "mycompany-commons_2.11" % "1.0"`
- Rebuild your parent project and it should be able to use the code in the package you created above

Learn More:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects

Comment: Testing it today, sounds good thou! Thanks, I'll comment/solve soon! ;)